# Showing a complex function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

If I know that a function $f$ is entire and $f(z)=f(z+1)=f(z+i)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, how do I show that $f(z)$ is constant?

I feel like this needs use of the uniqueness/identity theorem to show that $f(z) \equiv g(z)$ for $g(z)$ some constant function. However, this requires defining some set $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with a limit point. I have no idea how to even approach this. What set of points would have a relevant limit point?

A quick sketch shows that this should be obvious; I'm just really not sure how to prove it.

Having looked at other questions, a lot of people have used Liouville's Theorem but I don't see how it applies in this case since I do not think the function is bounded. What is the correct approach to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove that $f$ is bounded and apply Liouville's theorem.

Let $K=\{z=x+i\,y:0\le x,y\le1\}$. Since $K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous on $K$, $f$ is bounded on $K$. By periodicity
$$
\{f(z):z\in\mathbb{C}\}=\{f(z):z\in K\}.
$$
Thus $f$ is bounden on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But how is it bounded?

Comment: @AccioHogwarts If Julián's hint is not enough, note that $f$ is the same function in every square $[n,n+1]\times [n,n+1]$, $n\in \Bbb Z$. But $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is compact, and $f$ is continuous...

Comment: @ Pedro Tamaroff): I also still don't understand how it is bounded........

Comment: I have included the proof of boundedness.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the square $P := \{a + bi : 0 \le a \le 1, 0 \le b \le 1\}$. Given $z = x + yi$, let $m$ and $n$ the greatest integer in $x$ and $y$, respectively. Then $z - (m + ni) = (x - m) + (y - n)i \in P$. This shows that every complex number $z$ is of the form $m + ni + w$ where $m,n \in \Bbb Z$ and $w\in P$. It follows from the double periodicity of $f$ that for every $z\in \Bbb C$, there exists $w\in P$ such that $f(z) = f(w)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $P$ and $P$ is compact, $f$ is bounded on $P$. Therefore, $f$ is bounded on $\Bbb C$. By the Liouville theorem, $f$ is constant.